# trying install mongodb on fedora

Tags: linux, typescript, mongodb, fedora, dnf

My laptop OS is the fedora37, and i need install mongodb, but when i execute `sudo dnf install mongodb-org` system returns:

Não sei mais o que fazer, alguem me ajuda pelo amor de deus

```
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package mongodb-org-4.2.0-1.el7.x86_64 from mongodb-4.2 requires mongodb-org-shell = 4.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
[...]
  - nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mongodb-org-shell-4.2.9-1.el7.x86_64 from mongodb-4.2
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Thanks

Comment: i follow this tutorial https://yashgarudkar.medium.com/how-to-install-mongodb-4-2-on-fedora-32-31-30-29-48464905d6a1

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install a package for CentOS 7 (that's the `.el7` part of the name) on Fedora 37. I wouldn't expect that to work because the software versions in those two distributions vary greatly.

Comment: On Fedora I build it from source.  It needs lots of build tools, RAM, disk space, and time, but it works great.